# How to pass the value from one class instance to another in javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have two class instances and i need to the pass the value from the first instance and make use of the passed value in the second class

Comment: `instance2.setValue(instance1.getValue());` or `instance2.value = instance1.value;`

Comment: A little more explanation, and a code would help. 
How do you wanna use the value in the second class?